# Add-PnPView group by secondary field

Tags: list, powershell, list-view, caml-query, pnp-powershell

I have created a script to create number of views in SharePoint, but I am unable to work out the CAML to group by more than one field if it's possible.

1 field being:

```
<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="num" /></GroupBy>
```

So 2 is?

Comment: Did you try adding 2 GroupBy elements, like: `<GroupBy></GroupBy><GroupBy></GroupBy>`? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, just picks up the first value supplied and ignores the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested on SharePoint 2016 - the correct syntax that worked for me to group by two fields is `<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="ColumnInternalName1" /><FieldRef Name="ColumnInternalName2" /></GroupBy>`.

Just make sure that you reference the columns by their internal name.

[SharePoint Column/Field Display Name vs Internal Name](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/06/sharepoint-field-display-name-vs-internal-name.html)

Comment: You are correct, odd I’m sure I tried that first 

Comment: Glad it got sorted out. :)